# What is the difference between the potential energy and potential function in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, potential-energy, terminology, definition

In quantum mechanics, we study particles in various systems, such as an infinite potential well, a finite potential well, potential barriers, potential steps, harmonic oscillators, and so on. In all these examples, we talk about the potential function.

My question is: Are the [potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy) of the particle and the [potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential) function the same thing or not? Please clarify the difference between the two.

Comment: The potential energy are you referring to is classical or quantum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In quantum mechanics you have that particles are states belonging to an Hilbert space.

The potential function you are talking about it's not really a function, it's an operator defined pointwise.
Such an operator, $\hat{V}(x)$, acts on states and is defined a priori even without states present.

The potential energy of a particle is the eigenvalue you have when acting on the state with the potential operator.

Given $|\alpha\rangle$ as an eigenstate of the potential you have:

$\hat{V}(x)|\alpha\rangle = \nu|\alpha\rangle$

$\hat{V}(x)$ is the potential operator (what you called function but really is an operator) and $\nu$ is the potential energy of your particle.

Note: in a potential well you usually have a quantization of the energy levels, so you are expected to have many $\nu$ and many eigenstates.

Comment: Is the Potential energy operator is defined based on the classical potential energy function of the system? For example for classical harmonic oscillator potential energy function is $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. Then the corresponding operator will be same but now $x$ will be considered as position operator! And when position operator will act upon eigen state of position it will simply act as a multiplicative operator?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happens for an harmonic potential, and all the other classical-based potentials. Notice that you could also encounter potentials based on spin interactions, those are purely quantum mechanical ones and have no classical counterparts. For the classical potentials instead your reasoning is correct: you promote to operators che observables of classical physics and you have your quantum potential operator!

Comment: @DineshKatoch  How the potentials used in your early quantum mechanics course come about is actually a complex subject. Sometimes they come from the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, where the energy levels of a higher energy system become the potential of a lower energy system (explains the potential that binds two atoms in a molecule). Sometimes quantum field theory tells us the potential between two fundamental particles, then that potential can be inserted into the Schrodinger equation (to explain, for example, the 1/r potential in hydrogen). There are other cases that dont fit in a comment.

Comment: Yes, for example the usual harmonic potential comes out in condensed matter systems or molecular systems from the approximation @AXensen brought up, or nuclear potential in $\alpha$ decay comes out from the QCD theory

Answer (score 2):

There no longer is a single "potential energy of the particle." Just like the particle doesn't have a position, but position is an operator. The particle doesn't have a potential; the potential is an operator. If you tried to measure the potential, it would have a range of possible values.

However a particle can approximately have a single value for its potential if it's very localized. If the particle's wavefunction is a small wavepacket... small compared to the size of variations in the potential, then the uncertainty in the potential might be small. This is the circumstance where a single particle can "have a potential."

[Take a look at this animation of a wavepacket in a harmonic oscillator](https://dml.riken.jp/squeezing/squeezed/sq_animations2/).